# Should the "Careers 2.0" box have the same highlighting as the questions?

Tags: feature-request, tags, jobs, tag-highlighting

Should the "Careers 2.0" box highlight (Favorite Tags) or fade (Ignored Tags) the job listings?

If you have tags you like or are an expert at, should you see them highlighted?

Comment: good point here